# SL5 OOB: Enable Drag 'n Drop for TreeVIewItem

Tags: drag-and-drop, silverlight-5.0, out-of-browser

I am trying to get drag 'n drop working to be able to drag files on to my SL5 OOB app.  I have gotten it working with a TextBox, but can't get it to work with TreeView/TreeViewItem.

Here's the xaml:

```
<sdk:TreeView Style="{StaticResource TreeViewStyle1}"   
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AllowDrop="True" Drop="AnyDropTarget_OnDrop">  
      <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" AllowDrop="True" Drop="AnyDropTarget_OnDrop" />  
       </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</sdk:TreeView>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any insights....
**UPDATE**:
It appears the OOB app has to be started from the local computer; when started from VS2012, d 'n d appears not to work at all.

In the xaml above, is it possible to make the TreeViewItem the drop target in addition to/instead of the TextBlock?
**UPDATE THE SECOND**:
What's the best way to extract the TreeView.ItemTemplate to make it easily 'styleable'?

Comment: "Require Elevated Trust when running OOB" is set to true, btw.

Comment: Added add'l info to original post.

Comment: Added a question about TreeView.ItemTemplate.